# Adding seconds to time variable

Tags: sas

```
*data final; 
   set final;
 duration = redate-ondate;
 dudays = floor(duration/86400);
 duhrs = floor((duration-(dudays*86400))/3600);
 dumins = floor((duration-(dudays*86400+duhrs*3600))/60);

****************Set up new variable duration**************;
attrib dur length=$11.;
if ae_term ne 'None' and dudays ne . then 
  dur = left(put(dudays,z2.))||':'||left(put(duhrs,z2.))||':'||left(put(dumins,z2.));
else dur = '';
run;*
```

I have this code but need to calculate seconds and concatenate to dur as I have an adverse event that is less than a minute so won't display. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: To be clear, `redate` and `ondate` are actually *datetime* and not *dates*?

Comment: @bbaird Correct

Comment: Wouldn't the issue be with the IF statement though? Specifically this section, `dudays ne .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the remaining seconds and then append to your time string like this:

```
 dusec = duration-(dudays*86400+duhrs*3600+dumins*60);

if ae_term ne 'None' and dudays ne . then 
  dur = left(put(dudays,z2.))||':'||left(put(duhrs,z2.))||':'||left(put(dumins,z2.)||':'||left(put(dusec,z2.)));
```

One note - using `put(dudays,z2.)` assumes your duration is never more than 99 days.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this should simplify things somewhat:

```
dudays  = FLOOR(duration/86400);
duhrs   = FLOOR(MOD(duration,86400)/3600); 
dumins  = FLOOR(MOD(duration,3600)/60);
dusec   = MOD(duration,60);
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two datetime values is a number of seconds (so it is also a datetime value).  You can use the DATEPART() and TIMEPART() function to divide into the number of days and seconds since midnight.  The TOD11.2 format will display seconds in HH:MM:SS.mm style.

```
length dur $20;
if n(redate,ondate)=2 and ae_term not in (' ','None') then do;
  duration = redate-ondate;
  dur = catx(':',datepart(duration),put(timepart(duration),tod11.2));
end;
```